# How to install poppler-utils on godaddy server without ssh

Tags: php, laravel, poppler, pdf-to-html

I just want to install poppler-utils on my development server to convert pdf to HTML. But unfortunately, I don't have SSH access. has somebody known how to install it without SSH?

Comment: ***It's not possible to install it without SSH***. Contact the server Admin, and you shall receive.

Comment: will sudo apt-get work if they give the SSH access?

Comment: Every single Linux command will work.(As I know)

Comment: Is there any command without sudo that install the poppler

Comment: If windows server *yes, you can double click to install*, P. use it, man. Tell your admin No Nuclear Launch mission is configured with the `Sudo` command.

Comment: @AbbasMastan just giving access may or may not give you `sudo apt` (depending upon whether the user is added to the sudoer group or not).